# ¿Cómo posicionar botón a la derecha de input file en columna de tabla bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo un error en una tabla en Bootstrap 3. La tabla tiene 3 inputs por fila (nombre + rut+ archivo) y quiero poner un botón de eliminar fila en cada fila de la tabla justo después del ultimo input (type file), menos en la primera fila (porque se debe especificar al menos una fila) pero el botón me queda debajo del input file no a la derecha como lo quiero. Entonces, ¿que será lo que pasa que el botón no me queda en la derecha del input file?. Les adjunto una captura de la tabla. ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser?

He editado el padding de la última columna al vuelo pero aun así el botón no sube a la derecha del input file.

[image: imagen de la tabla en cuestión]

Primero que todo gracias por sus aportes. La primera fila existe siempre en la carga del DOM, es decir la tabla inicialmente tiene su encabezado y una sola fila (la cual no tiene botón eliminar fila). Las demás filas se van agregando dinamicamente al presionar el boton Agregar Fila. Les dejo el código de la tabla y del bloque jQuery que crea cada fila. 
Por otro lado no creo que sea un problema de espacio restante en la celda de la tabla, porque probé creando el mismo botón en la columna rut (la cual tiene más espacio) y pasa lo mismo, es decir, el boton es posicionado abajo del input o en una nueva linea. A todo esto el botón en si es un elemento anchor con clase btn btn-danger.

```js
/* inicio del bloque que agrega una fila a la tabla */
     
     var conteo = 1;
     $("#add_row").click(function() {
      
   if(conteo<10 ||   $('.ruttabl1').length < 10) {
            
$('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(conteo)+'"></tr>');
$('#addr'+conteo).html("<td class='order'>"+ (conteo) +"</td> <td>  <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-12'> <input name='nombres_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' placeholder='Ingrese nombre completo' class='form-control txtVal' required><span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='nombre_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-10'> <input name='ruts_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+"' type='text' maxlength='12' placeholder='Ingrese RUT' class='form-control ruttabl1' required> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='rut_s1t1_"+conteo+1+"'></span></div></td> <td> <div class='form-group has-feedback col-md-11'><input type='file' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+"' name='archivo_s1t1_array["+conteo+"]' required> <span class='glyphicon form-control-feedback' id='archivo_s1t1_array"+conteo+1+"'></span> <a class='btn-remove-tr btn btn-danger' style='float:left'>Eliminar fila</a>  <div id='errorBlock"+conteo+"' class='help-block'></div>  <span id='fileErrorValidMsg"+conteo+"' class='file-val-error'></span><br><span style='color:red'></span> </div> </td>"); 
                          
   conteo++;
            
  /* inicio actualizacion numeros de filas */ 
   if($('#tab_logic tr').length > 1) {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      $('#tab_logic td.order').text(function (i) {  return i + 1; });
                     }
  /* fin actualizacion numeros de fila */
                     
       }
 
   
    });
    
/* cierre del bloque que agrega una fila a la tabla */

  /* inicio bloque de eliminación de fila de la tabla */

     
        var i = $('#tab_logic tr').length;
        $('#tab_logic').on('click', '.btn-remove-tr', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
                
        if($('#tab_logic tr').length>1) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            $('td.order').text(function (i) {
                return i + 1;
            });
        }
        
        if($('#tab_logic tr').length<10) { $('#add_row').show();  }
        return false;
        });
  /* fin bloque de eliminación de fila de la tabla */
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- inicio tabla  -->
                                

   <div class="row clearfix ">
    
      
           <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <label class="control-label"><p><small>5. Nombre(s) y RUTs y Archivos (*)</small></p></label>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sm" id="tab_logic" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                   
                    <thead class="thead-inverse bg-primary">
                        <tr class="cabecera">
                            <th class="text-center"><p>#</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center"><p>Nombre Completo (*)</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center"><p>RUT (*)</p></th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                            <p>
                                Adjuntar documento (*)
                                </p>
                            </th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       
                    <tr id="addr0">
                        <td class="order">
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-12">
                              <input type="text"  id="nombre_s1t1_0" name="nombres_s1t1_array[0]" placeholder="Ingrese nombre completo" class="form-control" required>
                              <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="nombre_s1t1_01"></span>
                          </div>
                        </td>

                     
                        <td>
                      
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" name="ruts_s1t1_array[0]" id="rut_s1t1_0" placeholder="Ingrese RUT" maxlength="12" class="form-control ruttabl1" required>  

                            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="rut_s1t1_01"></span> 

                      
                              </div>     
                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-md-11">
                              <input type="file" id="archivo_s1t1_array0" name="archivo_s1t1_array[0]" required>

                              <div id="errorBlock0" class="help-block"></div>
                              <span id="fileErrorValidMsg0" class="file-val-error"></span>
                          
                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                  
                                       
                </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
                   
                               
        <div style="float:right">
          <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary addnewrow pull-left">Agregar fila
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </a> 
        </div>


        </br> </br>
<!-- fin tabla -->
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código HTML de la tabla y el CSS que aplique a estos elementos. Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: Se te está bajando a la siguiente línea porque no caben dentro del contenedor en la misma línea y por eso baja a la siguiente. Sin embargo, deberías agregar tu código para que podamos saber cual es tu problema exactamente.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código en un solo ejemplo usando Cntrl+M y poniendo el código correspondiente en cada casilla. JQuery por un lado y HTML por otro.

Comment: Ahi agregué bien el código @Error404 ojalá se entienda

Comment: Ahi agregué bien el código @Mariano ojalá se entienda

Comment: @Sebastian Sin embargo, en tu foto hay dos inputs y en este caso solo aparece el de eliminar cuando agregamos una nueva fila. ¿Es el código que has añadido el del diseño actual? ¿O sería diferente?

Comment: @Error404 en la foto hay 3 inputs en todas las filas pero el boton eliminar fila solo lo tienen las filas 2 a la 10 porque el usuario no debe eliminar la primera fila que es la obligatoria. Y el diseño de la foto es el mismo del código

Answer (score 3):

Podrías probar asignadoles porcentaje a las columnas dándole un mayor tamaño a la columna que deseas ocupar, y otra solución sería asignando dentro de la columna lo siguiente

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-8">Primer input</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">Segundo input</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Revisa estos ejemplos :-) espero que te sean de utilidad.

```html
<link href="http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>File</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input id="Examinar" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6" name="Examinar" placeholder="Seleccione un archivo" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-xs-2">Examinar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-2">Boton 2</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input id="Examinar" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6" name="Examinar" placeholder="Seleccione un archivo" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Examinar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Boton 2</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input id="Examinar" type="text" class="form-control col-xs-6" name="Examinar" placeholder="Seleccione un archivo" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-xs-3">Examinar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-3">Boton 2</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="Examinar" type="text" class="form-control" name="Examinar" placeholder="Seleccione un archivo" />
          <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default">Examinar</span>
          <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">Boton 2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
          <input id="Examinar" type="text" class="form-control" name="Examinar" placeholder="Seleccione un archivo" />
          <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default">Examinar</span>
          <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">Boton 2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero debes asegurar que tus input no tengan un tamaño fijo. por que so puede causar que tu boton baje por defecto responsi...

pero creo que esto te puede ayudar..

a tus dos botones agragale un style fijo. ejemplo

```
< button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="display: inline-block;">botones de prueba</button>

< button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="display: inline-block;">botones de prueba</button>
```

y deberia quedar como quieres. saludos

Comment: Si esta usando `bootstrap` creo que es mas recomendable usar las clases y bondades del mismo y no hacer las cosas "a pie"

Answer (score 1):

Mira a ver si en el css el elemento que tratas de posicionar tiene la propiedad **display:block;** trata de cambiarlo a **display:inline-block;**

Aquí tienes más info:

https://librosweb.es/referencia/css/display.html

Cerciórate también de que tiene la propiedad **float:left;** podría servirte para posicionar elementos en fila.

Aunque el problema podría ser debido a que el botón simplemente no cabe justo detrás de donde lo quieres colocar y por eso se sale del contenedor.

Lo mismo te sería más práctico en vez de añadir demasiado texto al botón, añadir una sola **X**.

La próxima vez trata de incluir en tu pregunta algo de código, aunque sea el css que tratas de modificar.

Saludos

Comment: Realmente el problema en este caso parece claramente que el elemento no cabe en el espacio disponible y por eso salta a la siguiente línea. Realmente no creo que usar la propiedad `float:left` sea una posible solución ya que los `input` por defecto son elementos `inline` y, por tanto, si hay espacio disponible, se pondrán en la misma línea si hay espacio disponible.

Comment: Seguramente, pero bootstrap se caracteriza por ser responsive, no estoy muy puesto en bootstrap la verdad.

Comment: Sí, el problema es que los elementos input son inline y por tanto no pueden obtener anchura. Por cierto, un apunte, es inline-block no inline:block.

Comment: Cierto, voy a corregirlo, muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la clase de la misma bootstrap la misma te agrupa los botones y te realiza el lineado de los mismos

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Izquierdo</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Central</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Derecho</button>
</div>
```